# Prove absolute convergence given that the $n \geq k$ terms are the same sign

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Prove: **If the terms of a convergent series $\sum a_{n}$ have the same sign for $n \geq k$, then $\sum a_{n}$ converges absolutely.**

It seems to make sense when reading it, but I'm not sure I understand where to start my proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

absolut convergence is with |..|. If you know that after an $n_0$ they all have the same sign you can take out of the sum the first $n_0 -1$ terms. They are finite number so doesn't care becouse they are finish. If the terms after $n_0$ are positive at that point you are looking already for absolut convergence. If the terms after $n_0$ are negative you just have to put a - in front of the sum and you will be looking for absolut convergence.